# what kind of thing would nulify a criminal trespass warning

Tags: trespass

I live in Atlanta, Ga. One of my neighbors was recently taken to jail for a criminal trespass. He entered the property and was there for about two hours the police were called. what is the law on such an event in my state?

Comment: The Georgia criminal trespass statute is fairly wrong.  Defense against being charged would be that an element of the charge does not apply.  Nothing was damaged, no unlawful purpose, etc.   Also, he wasn't warned, he was arrested.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [GA's Title 16 Chapter 7 Article 2 Part 1](https://law.justia.com/codes/georgia/2022/title-16/chapter-7/article-2/part-1/section-16-7-21/), the owner of the property could have alleged your neighbor damaged the property, and the damage was valued at $500 or less or your neighbor was allegedly using the property without the consent of the property's owner. Whether the allegations at the time of the event were true or made up, we don't know. However, the property owner (where your neighbor was) had the authority to initiate, call the cops, and file charges.